# reCaptchaのサーバー側認証方法を変更できますか?

Tags: recaptcha

reCaptchaを使っております。
その際、サーバーサイドで認証情報の書かれたjsonファイルを置いた場所のpathを環境変数GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALSに書くことで、Googleへの認証が行われますが、このjsonの内容をファイルに置かずに、プログラムコード上に記述した変数などから渡すことは可能でしょうか?
言語はGoを使っていますが他の言語での情報でも構いません。

実際にはコード上に認証情報を置くようなことはしません。説明を簡単にするためにそう表現しております。

よろしくお願いいたします。